# How can authenticate an user without password in AdonisJs in Jwt mode?

Tags: authentication, jwt, adonis.js

how can authenticate users without password in AdonisJs in jwt mode?

i work with sms verification code.if code match, user is authenticated. so dont need to password. but adonis jwt `attempt` method need password.

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
await auth.generate(user);
```

example:

```
async login({request, response, auth}) {
    const {verification_code, mobile} = request.all();
    let user = await User.findBy('mobile', mobile);
    if (user && await Hash.verify(verification_code, user.verification_code)) {
        response.json(await auth.generate(user));
    }
}
```